# How to copy a calculated value to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, variables, clipboard

I've got a formula that calculates a value. This value I want to insert to an Excel sheet. To make it comfortable to the user I want to put it to the clipboard automatically.

I try to do my first steps in JS and encountered this (probably) very simple problem. But all methods I found are related to raw values of html input-tags. I never have seen any copy-to-clipboard functions from values created in js.

```
var EEFactor = 1*1; // just a formula to calculate a value
copyValue2Clipboard(EEFactor);

function value2Clipboard(value) {
// please help
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example with a great explanation [here](https://techoverflow.net/2018/03/30/copying-strings-to-the-clipboard-using-pure-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
function copyToClipboard(str) {
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
   // Set value (string to be copied)
   el.value = str;
   // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
   el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
   el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
   document.body.appendChild(el);
   // Select text inside element
   el.select();
   // Copy text to clipboard
   document.execCommand('copy');
   // Remove temporary element
   document.body.removeChild(el);
};

var EEFactor = 1*1;

copyToClipboard(EEFactor);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');  // Create a <textarea> element

  el.value = str;                                 // Set its value to the string that you want copied

  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');                // Make it readonly to be tamper-proof

  el.style.position = 'absolute';                 
  el.style.left = '-9999px';                      // Move outside the screen to make it invisible

  document.body.appendChild(el);                  // Append the <textarea> element to the HTML document

  const selected =            
      document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0        // Check if there is any content selected previously
      ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)     // Store selection if found
      : false;                                    // Mark as false to know no selection existed before

  el.select();                                    // Select the <textarea> content

  document.execCommand('copy');                   // Copy - only works as a result of a user action (e.g. click events)

  document.body.removeChild(el);                  // Remove the <textarea> element

  if (selected) {                                 // If a selection existed before copying

    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();    // Unselect everything on the HTML document

    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);   // Restore the original selection

  }
};
```